# Understanding Accessor Function (d)

Tags: d3.js

```
var cs1 = drawCircles(svg1,data,d=>d["A"],d=>d["B"],sc1);
```

Trying to get an intuitive understanding for how d is used when binding. 
The above function calls `.append('circle')` and uses the two access functions `d=>d["A"]`,`d=>d["B"]` to place the circles.

I understand that d essentially acts as an iterable on 'data' and that here we are implicitly returning `d['B']`. What I don't understand is why we cant simply pass d in a non function way e.g. `drawCircles(...,d['A'] ,...)`. When I've tried using d in this manner it returns d is not defined.

Using a simpler example,

```
svg.selectAll('circle').data(data).enter.append('circle')
  .attr('id', (d) => {return d['name']})
```

Why can't I simply supply `d['name']` for the 2nd arg of `.attr()`

How can I reason about the use of d solely as a function argument?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why the code didnt render... sorry about that!

Answer (score 3):

**The 2nd Parameter of .style()/.attr()**

When using something like:

```
.attr("fill", someParameter);
```

D3 checks to see if `someParameter` is a function or a constant.

If `someParameter` is a constant, "all elements are given the same attribute value", afterall we're using a constant. ([see also, D3 documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_attr)).

If `someParameter` is a function, D3 uses `function.apply()` ([see also, MDN's function.apply() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)) to call that function for each item in the selection, providing it with 3 parameters:

- the current datum (by convention `d`),
- the index of the current item (by convention `i`),
- and the group of nodes in the selection (inconsistent convention, I'll use `nodes` here).

*The use of apply also allows specification of `this`, which is the current element (which is also: `nodes[i]`).*

The use of function.apply() defines `d`, `i`, and `nodes` only within the function provided.

This makes sense, if you provide a constant, there is nothing to apply, er, apply to and no need to.

---

**What happens when you supply d['name'] as the 2nd argument for .style()/.attr()**

If using:

```
.attr("fill", d.color)`
```

`d` in the above has no relation to the datum. If you haven't declared `d` and given it the property `color` yourself, it'll be undefined here. D3 doesn't call a function here with apply to define `d` - you aren't providing a function to do so with.

Only if `d.color` evaluates to `function(d) { return d.color; }` would you be able to do what you are asking about. *This would be a very unusual form with D3*.

If `d` is undefined you'll likely throw an error when accessing `d.color` as you've seen. If `d` is defined, but `d.color` isn't a function, it'll be treated as a constant and every element will gain a property with the same value.

Consequently, this is why we see the format:

```
.attr("fill", function(d,i,nodes) { return ... });
```

---

**Stop Here**

*It is possible in theory, but not advisable, to accomplish what you think should be possible.*

I'm only sharing because

- I've had this lying around for a while
- It shows how much of a workaround is required to achieve the pattern you are asking about (without pre-defining your functions as properties of some object named `d`).

Again it's not advisable to use - but you can, *technically*, dynamically create an accessor function for a given property, or nested property, of the datum with a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

With this you could use the form:

```
.attr("fill", d.color)
```

When accessing any of the proxy (`d`) properties (here `color`) it would need to return the appropriate accessor function (`function(d) { return d.color;}`) which would then be passed to `.attr()` and have the appropriate datum bound to it. *You can only use the property, you wouldn't be able to use `d.x + 2`*.

```js
// create a proxy `d` to return accessor functions, 
var d = new Proxy({},{ get: f })

var data = [
  {style:{fill:"steelblue",stroke:{color:"crimson", width:4}},width: 30, y: 50, x: 10},
  {style:{fill:"yellow",stroke:{color:"orange", width:2}},width: 20, y: 50, x: 50},
  {style:{fill:"crimson",stroke:{color:"steelblue", width:8}},width: 30, y: 50, x: 80}
]

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", d.x)
  .attr("y", d.y)
  .attr("width", d.width)
  .attr("height",d.width)
  .attr("fill",d.style.fill)
  .attr("stroke-width",d.style.stroke.width)
  .attr("stroke", d.style.stroke.color);
  
  
  
// To resolve paths (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45322101/7106086):
function resolve(path, obj) {
    return path.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
        return prev ? prev[curr] : null
    }, obj || self)
}
// Proxy to dynamically access properties of any depth:
function f(obj, prop) {
    if(prop in obj) return obj[prop];
    else { 
       var g = function() {
          var accessor = function(d) {
            return resolve(accessor._path_,d);
          }
          // keep track of path:
          if(obj._path_) accessor._path_ = [...obj._path_,prop];
          else (accessor._path_) = [prop];
          return accessor;
       }
       return obj[prop] = new Proxy(g(), {get:f});     
    }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As this seems to be a beginner's question of sorts I am not sure if this is really helpful to OP. It will definitely earn you one of those invisible *Sickness* gold badges, though ;-)

Comment: @altocumulus, To be honest, it was more of a lark with you and Gerardo in mind.